# ASP.NET MVC Web Deploy won't override Default Web Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a rather large ASP.NET MVC project that I'm trying to deploy to a Windows Server 2016 VM on a remote machine. The deploy works in that I can go into IIS manager and see `Views`, `Content` etc under `Default Web Site` but I can't view the website itself. It defaults to the IIS starter page.

I was previously battling some `web.config` errors and the `<modules>` section in my `web.config` was causing an Internal 500 error. I've commented out the following code and it stopped the error:

```
<modules>
  <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
  <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

But now `Default Web Site` defaults back to it's previous state, the initial IIS website. It's not a caching issue, multiple computers/browsers are seeing the same website.

Here's a screenshot of `Default Web Site` as per the IIS server:

[image: IIS]

I'm stumped on this. At least with the internal 500 error I knew that *my site* was causing the issue, but this seems to be overriding any config that I have set in my project.

I've had to copy my `ApplicationHost.config` into a pastebin link because of the character limit on StackOverflow:

https://pastebin.com/0K0TDgTh

My experience with ASP.NET deployment and IIS is limited to literally this morning so I'm not sure what I'm looking for, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to set up a domain name / subdomain or an alias to access your Website?

Comment: No. The website is on a server inhouse, the default website is being shown despite my project overriding the files that exist in `Default Web Site`.

Comment: I read the ApplicationHost.config and the problem is this:  <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>

Check that these files are removed from the root of the Website.

Nevertheless, I wrote a small guide in my answer so you can set up your site without having to overwrite the default site, hope it helps.

Comment: It ended up being `Application Development` not being installed by the network admin when setting up the IIS server. I really appreciate your help though!

Comment: Cool! glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of overwriting the default website you could disable it and create a new virtual host for your site:

**Application Pool**

It is always a good practice to run each application on its own application pool so if one application fails it won't affect the other applications running on the same server and also it allows to select different versions of .NET framework for each application.

To create an application pool, right click on "Application Pools" then "Add Application Pool", fill up the name and select the .NET framework version.

If your application is 32 bits or contains 32 bits modules you need to enable 32-bit application support, to do that, right click on the newly created application pool in the list of application pools and then click on "Advance Settings" and set "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to True:

[image: Enable 32-Bit Applications]

Other settings you may want to configure here are the startup mode and the process model identity, although the default should work for your needs.

**Set up your site**

Stop the Default Web Site by clicking on its name and then on "Stop" under the "Manage Website" section of the right column.

Then, right click on "Sites" and "Add Web Site", fill up the name and select the application pool you created before, choose your port (normally 80), leave IP address as it is and select the physical path of your Website.

[image: New IIS Web Site window]

Click OK and ignore any warnings about using the same port as an existing Website. Your site should be up and running now from http://localhost

Now, you need to either delete the Default Website (right click, delete) or you need to change the port to something other than 80 which you are already using for your new site, to change the port, right click on Default Website and then "Edit Bindings" and delete the binding or edit it to change the port.

**Web Deploy**

Web Deploy might already work for you but to make sure, right click on your Web Site name and then configure Web Deploy again for the new site.